# Why is the U1 sharing dialog so unhelpful?

Tags: ubuntu-one

On the web, it is very easy to share a folder from Ubuntu One with another user (more>share  folder and enter email address). However, on the desktop right-clicking a folder, selecting Ubuntu One > Share brings up a window that looks like this:
[image]

It is utterly unhelpful, not even providing a field to enter an email address.

Can anyone else make sense of this?

Comment: You're right, that looks like a work in progress. The FAQ explaining it [is here](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/tutorial/install-and-setup-file-sync/) (scroll down about halfway). Bottom line is you have to have contacts in your Ubuntu One Address Book first, then it works fine.

Comment: @TomBrossman That is not entirely true. You do not have to add contacts to the "Ubuntu One" address book. They simply have to be accessible via evolution-data-server.

Comment: @dobey Is evolution-data-server present in a default install? If not, which is the easiest way to get this functionality working?

Comment: @TomBrossman It is, as the calendar and address book in most of the default apps in Ubuntu requires it. I don't know that Thunderbird uses it by default though.

Comment: @TomBrossman I'm using a default 12.04 installation, and I have added two contacts to my U1 address book (on the web) to check if this makes a difference. It doesn't. This may be because I haven't explicitly set it up to sync my U1 address book locally. In any event this is very unintuitive, since even to an experienced Ubuntu user like me it is not clear at all where my local address book data is stored and how to interact with it.

Answer (score 3):

It is implemented as per the design which was made for it. There is an open bug at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client-gnome/+bug/720194 about this.

Comment: Well, the behaviour is completely broken if on a system of the average new user (with no U1 contacts), there is no indication at all of what one should do to actually share the folder. In fact, a dialog simply saying "go to the website" would be more helpful. I am also dismayed to find that that bug report has received so little attention.

Comment: Just to say, I'm grateful for the answer, just disappointed that there isn't a better solution.